# How to change point size in lattice?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

How can I modify "point" sizes proportionally to a given variable?

For example with ggplot I can do it with

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point(aes(size=mysize))+geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id))
```

where mysize is the size of every point I want.
but it's very slow when the dataset is big.

I've tried with lattice:

```
xyplot(y~x , type="b", col="black", col.line="blue", data=mydata, pch=16, lwd=1 )
```

But I can't find a working way to use a size= option with lattice.

I've tried the cex option but it produces strange results.

This is a simplified version of my data: (it's a data.table but you can use a data.frame if you want)

```
structure(list(id = c(3059L, 1161L, 3996L, 6330L, 6675L, 1511L, 
3678L, 294L, 596L, 2440L, 446L, 2635L, 6073L, 3709L, 744L, 4997L, 
3495L, 6447L, 6693L, 1040L, 1031L, 690L, 352L, 6311L, 2599L, 
6425L, 3758L, 690L, 6742L, 3025L, 6348L, 214L, 222L, 8192L, 615L, 
2939L, 5351L, 255L, 1531L, 6426L, 1686L, 2677L, 1919L, 3665L, 
6514L, 630L, 820L, 2138L, 6695L, 1323L, 6246L, 2102L, 2600L, 
3663L, 3851L, 970L, 1124L, 4071L, 1806L, 4579L, 3395L, 4371L, 
1466L, 201L, 2112L, 8653L, 4407L, 1959L, 6341L, 2214L, 6515L, 
1390L, 6346L, 5373L, 662L, 2198L, 1971L, 6177L, 4652L, 4420L, 
6527L, 2704L, 6366L, 1111L, 6156L, 151L, 734L, 4286L, 5085L, 
2359L, 2818L, 339L, 8486L, 5303L, 5076L, 8490L, 1230L, 1884L, 
5204L, 2880L, 8463L, 215L, 6778L, 6329L, 5797L, 584L, 4831L, 
4806L, 2581L, 3972L, 2298L, 3136L, 335L, 5538L, 1528L, 518L, 
3552L, 3874L, 1967L, 4333L, 3035L, 4112L, 215L, 1768L, 866L, 
3545L, 8085L, 8622L, 2844L, 2663L, 1356L, 4902L, 880L, 8219L, 
1486L, 3086L, 685L, 417L, 5966L, 221L, 8401L, 8378L, 1542L, 1815L, 
515L, 6262L, 3522L, 2440L, 182L, 946L, 3924L, 6219L, 2282L, 4165L, 
4969L, 5829L, 6707L, 4467L, 8645L, 8267L, 3960L, 1432L, 8203L, 
1691L, 5515L, 2005L, 5578L, 6732L, 103L, 740L, 8239L, 2037L, 
630L, 8286L, 4005L, 3874L, 1691L, 201L, 4191L, 1259L, 4476L, 
5210L, 798L, 5829L, 6499L, 120L, 1725L, 2185L, 3795L, 5918L, 
3474L, 936L, 4625L, 4449L, 5579L, 5906L, 2050L, 3376L, 6140L, 
8021L, 5009L, 3545L, 346L, 8513L, 1529L, 4155L, 3029L, 5785L, 
397L, 1448L, 1804L, 6209L, 3043L, 2448L, 8371L, 5729L, 1602L, 
5600L, 1488L, 280L, 1986L, 2858L, 1742L, 1939L, 4869L, 751L, 
2967L, 6350L, 612L, 3935L, 3972L, 8321L, 8225L, 8117L, 5181L, 
2214L, 1461L, 8150L, 3218L, 3699L, 4906L, 4488L, 1317L, 866L, 
6832L, 8394L, 527L, 1384L, 3356L, 3320L, 1951L, 2979L, 3884L, 
1664L, 8446L, 1851L, 1105L, 816L, 6323L, 4490L, 1020L, 3888L, 
1086L, 4804L, 1203L, 3464L, 836L, 1591L, 755L, 6332L, 221L, 3519L, 
1565L, 1169L, 2841L, 3992L, 5296L, 6187L, 3001L, 3711L, 1394L, 
3333L, 1728L, 4320L, 6670L, 4653L, 6409L, 2369L, 8428L, 3714L, 
8383L, 2142L, 1803L, 589L, 1986L, 866L, 866L, 4558L, 8139L, 3996L, 
3667L, 2939L, 4626L, 3950L, 4371L, 6036L, 3212L, 8534L, 1599L, 
1801L, 5015L, 121L, 8258L, 3811L, 1277L, 1161L, 4854L, 4581L, 
8150L, 3223L, 2939L, 8548L, 1691L, 2969L, 1705L, 3477L, 5351L, 
1120L, 3921L, 3915L, 2599L, 3457L, 630L, 2296L, 1569L, 6378L, 
3447L, 6438L, 2697L, 2236L, 675L, 6147L, 4842L, 6205L, 4453L, 
4478L, 2394L, 2115L, 5799L, 4683L, 1699L, 4757L, 8566L, 2125L, 
3365L, 5194L, 1448L, 2043L, 2549L, 8647L, 1542L, 6179L, 1706L, 
4099L, 5996L, 5289L, 6383L, 5102L, 488L, 889L, 3323L, 8461L, 
1673L, 919L, 661L, 6505L, 1624L, 8261L, 6118L, 3935L, 2288L, 
1230L, 1221L, 8359L, 8611L, 5710L, 6064L, 5238L, 2251L, 72L, 
678L, 1649L, 8304L, 6056L, 8294L, 1967L, 5914L, 536L, 6330L, 
8548L, 1111L, 3773L, 1381L, 3522L, 8461L, 1163L, 3111L, 3035L, 
8101L, 1705L, 1690L, 2988L, 2243L, 3921L, 6348L, 4683L, 8424L, 
3117L, 2015L, 559L, 8596L, 4235L, 280L, 8197L, 6096L, 3130L, 
2880L, 1224L, 3636L, 8291L, 108L, 3213L, 2386L, 3350L, 3526L, 
8116L, 2213L, 3519L, 1387L, 3672L, 4096L, 4288L, 905L, 3348L, 
380L, 876L, 1685L, 8636L, 5559L, 1630L, 4696L, 5068L, 2351L, 
757L, 3842L, 3517L, 8270L, 2880L, 8572L, 3384L, 6056L, 3884L, 
1259L, 1053L, 6262L, 3965L, 4401L, 5295L, 4467L, 8216L, 8197L, 
3500L, 5475L, 6662L, 2117L, 1092L, 5500L, 1447L, 6283L, 5930L, 
2486L, 3258L, 4272L, 1616L, 3024L, 4104L, 3760L, 4431L, 5830L, 
6366L, 5202L, 2868L, 5097L, 8647L, 6701L, 1167L, 5521L, 1209L, 
5979L, 6178L), cars = structure(c(11L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 
12L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 
9L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 
9L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 
13L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 
7L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 
11L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
9L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 
11L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 4L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 
8L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 
12L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 12L, 
7L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 
13L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 
12L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
12L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 6L, 13L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 13L, 
12L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 
9L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 
11L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
13L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 
3L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 8L, 
13L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 
3L, 12L, 11L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 
11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 7L, 
4L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 
13L, 9L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 
3L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 
8L, 11L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 
11L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 
13L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 6L, 8L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 
11L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 12L), .Label = c("FORD", 
"VW", "PEUGEOT", "RENAULT", "TOYOTA", "BMW", "NISSAN", "MB", 
"AUDI", "HONDA", "FIAT", "LR", "SKODA", "MAZDA", "MINI", "KIA", 
"VOLVO", "SEAT", "SUZUKI", "MITSU", "JAGUAR", "ROVER", "SAAB", 
"LEXUS", "CHEVRO", "MG", "PORSCHE"), class = "factor"), numb = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 9L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 13L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
16L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mysize = c(0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 
0.259604625139873, 0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.259604625139873, 0.0761772853185596, 0.00627177700348432, 0.0759581881533101, 
0.0655052264808362, 0.198433420365535, 0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 
0.167701863354037, 0.0759581881533101, 0.212543554006969, 0.120477433793361, 
0.0655052264808362, 0.0664819944598338, 0.061917195076464, 0.183673469387755, 
0.307479224376731, 0.0512465373961219, 0.120477433793361, 0.061917195076464, 
0.0484893696381947, 0.0759581881533101, 0.0982578397212544, 0.198433420365535, 
0.142857142857143, 0.0115628496829541, 0.259604625139873, 0.34402332361516, 
0.375, 0.259604625139873, 0.0982578397212544, 0.198433420365535, 
0.198433420365535, 0.0481163744871317, 0.0522648083623693, 0.282229965156794, 
0.282229965156794, 0.198433420365535, 0.34402332361516, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.061917195076464, 0.196195449459157, 0.120477433793361, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0759581881533101, 0.212543554006969, 0.259604625139873, 
0.212543554006969, 0.198433420365535, 0.198433420365535, 0.196195449459157, 
0.0662020905923345, 0.259604625139873, 0.307479224376731, 0.0759581881533101, 
0.061917195076464, 0.0625, 0.196195449459157, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 0.282229965156794, 0.0481163744871317, 
0.0982578397212544, 0.061917195076464, 0.0982578397212544, 0.196195449459157, 
0.0699708454810496, 0.212543554006969, 0.120477433793361, 0.0484893696381947, 
0.198433420365535, 0.00857888847444983, 0.212543554006969, 0.0682926829268293, 
0.0522648083623693, 0.444444444444444, 0.198433420365535, 0.212543554006969, 
0.0875, 0.061917195076464, 0.120477433793361, 0.259604625139873, 
0.307479224376731, 0.282229965156794, 0.0522648083623693, 0.375, 
0.259604625139873, 0.198433420365535, 0.282229965156794, 0.0759581881533101, 
0.307479224376731, 0.0759581881533101, 0.0682926829268293, 0.120477433793361, 
0.282229965156794, 0.0982578397212544, 0.307479224376731, 0.307479224376731, 
0.34402332361516, 0.198433420365535, 0.282229965156794, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0496894409937888, 0.054016620498615, 0.198433420365535, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0484893696381947, 0.259604625139873, 0.0682926829268293, 
0.0229965156794425, 0.196195449459157, 0.307479224376731, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0662020905923345, 0.0481163744871317, 0.4, 0.0699708454810496, 
0.259604625139873, 0.212543554006969, 0.21606648199446, 0.120477433793361, 
0.0655052264808362, 0.0761772853185596, 0.196195449459157, 0.198433420365535, 
0.259604625139873, 0.0759581881533101, 0.5, 0.120477433793361, 
0.259604625139873, 0.0728862973760933, 0.0522648083623693, 0.259604625139873, 
0.322981366459627, 0.198433420365535, 0.282229965156794, 0.282229965156794, 
0.282229965156794, 0.120477433793361, 0.259604625139873, 0.0115628496829541, 
0.198433420365535, 0.307479224376731, 0.21606648199446, 0.307479224376731, 
0.198433420365535, 0.0759581881533101, 0.0354345393509884, 0.0775623268698061, 
0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 
0.282229965156794, 0.054016620498615, 0.0728862973760933, 0.282229965156794, 
0.120477433793361, 0.282229965156794, 0.196195449459157, 0.307479224376731, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0522648083623693, 0.1, 0.198433420365535, 
0.198433420365535, 0.0775623268698061, 0.0125, 0.032069970845481, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0229965156794425, 0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 
0.307479224376731, 0.196195449459157, 0.0655052264808362, 0.061917195076464, 
0.120477433793361, 0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 0.0204081632653061, 
0.120477433793361, 0.0481163744871317, 0.0682926829268293, 0.282229965156794, 
0.0655052264808362, 0.198433420365535, 0.054016620498615, 0.259604625139873, 
0.282229965156794, 0.212543554006969, 0.198433420365535, 0.0683229813664596, 
0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 0.196195449459157, 0.282229965156794, 
0.0375, 0.212543554006969, 0.120477433793361, 0.183673469387755, 
0.0481163744871317, 0.0664819944598338, 0.0682926829268293, 0.198433420365535, 
0.307479224376731, 0.282229965156794, 0.0481163744871317, 0.307479224376731, 
0.0655052264808362, 0.212543554006969, 0.0522648083623693, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0138504155124654, 0.196195449459157, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0522648083623693, 0.212543554006969, 0.198433420365535, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.0484893696381947, 0.307479224376731, 0.259604625139873, 0.0759581881533101, 
0.282229965156794, 0.307479224376731, 0.0152354570637119, 0.0193905817174515, 
0.198433420365535, 0.183673469387755, 0.061917195076464, 0.0682926829268293, 
0.0982578397212544, 0.2, 0.0759581881533101, 0.198433420365535, 
0.120477433793361, 0.21606648199446, 0.061917195076464, 0.0522648083623693, 
0.259604625139873, 0.198433420365535, 0.196195449459157, 0.198433420365535, 
0.0484893696381947, 0.0193905817174515, 0.0875, 0.307479224376731, 
0.282229965156794, 0.5, 0.307479224376731, 0.212543554006969, 
0.0481163744871317, 0.0318559556786704, 0.0481163744871317, 0.198433420365535, 
0.0354345393509884, 0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.212543554006969, 0.0354345393509884, 0.0728862973760933, 0.0662020905923345, 
0.282229965156794, 0.21606648199446, 0.0512465373961219, 0.0662020905923345, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0655052264808362, 0.0229965156794425, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0664819944598338, 0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 0.196195449459157, 
0.0512465373961219, 0.212543554006969, 0.0664819944598338, 0.061917195076464, 
0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 0.120477433793361, 0.196195449459157, 
0.307479224376731, 0.259604625139873, 0.183673469387755, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0982578397212544, 0.0522648083623693, 0.282229965156794, 0.212543554006969, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0522648083623693, 0.0512465373961219, 0.34402332361516, 
0.212543554006969, 0.198433420365535, 0.259604625139873, 0.198433420365535, 
0.282229965156794, 0.198433420365535, 0.34402332361516, 0.196195449459157, 
0.307479224376731, 0.282229965156794, 0.0354345393509884, 0.0291545189504373, 
0.142857142857143, 0.322981366459627, 0.0664819944598338, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.5, 0.0481163744871317, 0.0664819944598338, 0.183673469387755, 
0.120477433793361, 0.0982578397212544, 0.196195449459157, 0.282229965156794, 
0.282229965156794, 0.0728862973760933, 0.5, 0.198433420365535, 
0.183673469387755, 0.0132404181184669, 0.259604625139873, 0.00484893696381947, 
0.00857888847444983, 0.34402332361516, 0.00484893696381947, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0115628496829541, 0.0132404181184669, 0.198433420365535, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.307479224376731, 0.198433420365535, 0.120477433793361, 0.031055900621118, 
0.0248447204968944, 0.196195449459157, 0.0982578397212544, 0.259604625139873, 
0.120477433793361, 0.0481163744871317, 0.375, 0.0318559556786704, 
0.307479224376731, 0.196195449459157, 0.0699708454810496, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0761772853185596, 0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 0.0229965156794425, 
0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 0.0484893696381947, 0.120477433793361, 
0.0115628496829541, 0.259604625139873, 0.196195449459157, 0.0354345393509884, 
0.196195449459157, 0.212543554006969, 0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0484893696381947, 0.0481163744871317, 0.196195449459157, 
0.120477433793361, 0.196195449459157, 0.322981366459627, 0.282229965156794, 
0.198433420365535, 0.21606648199446, 0.0662020905923345, 0.212543554006969, 
0.0775623268698061, 0.282229965156794, 0.0787172011661808, 0.0728862973760933, 
0.282229965156794, 0.0484893696381947, 0.0229965156794425, 0.282229965156794, 
0.0759581881533101, 0.061917195076464, 0.0682926829268293, 0.259604625139873, 
0.0222222222222222, 0.259604625139873, 0.212543554006969, 0.282229965156794, 
0.061917195076464, 0.212543554006969, 0.0484893696381947, 0.0662020905923345, 
0.198433420365535, 0.061917195076464, 0.34402332361516, 0.0682926829268293, 
1, 0.183673469387755, 0.282229965156794, 0.375, 0.259604625139873, 
0.282229965156794, 0.21606648199446, 0.0699708454810496, 0.307479224376731, 
0.0124223602484472, 0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 0.375, 
0.0152354570637119, 0.0248447204968944, 0.0761772853185596, 0.259604625139873, 
0.120477433793361, 0.0595567867036011, 0.259604625139873, 0.259604625139873, 
0.196195449459157, 0.120477433793361, 0.282229965156794, 0.198433420365535, 
0.198433420365535, 0.0982578397212544, 0.307479224376731, 0.307479224376731, 
0.259604625139873, 0.120477433793361, 0.0522648083623693, 0.198433420365535, 
0.259604625139873, 0.0662020905923345, 0.307479224376731, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.196195449459157, 0.0481163744871317, 0.282229965156794, 0.120477433793361, 
0.282229965156794, 0.282229965156794, 0.196195449459157, 0.0481163744871317, 
0.0982578397212544, 0.0481163744871317, 0.0522648083623693, 0.196195449459157, 
0.05, 0.196195449459157, 0.198433420365535, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.198433420365535, 0.322981366459627, 0.259604625139873, 0.05, 
0.34402332361516, 0.061917195076464, 0.198433420365535, 0.0655052264808362, 
0.054016620498615, 0.0481163744871317, 0.0662020905923345, 0.198433420365535, 
0.061917195076464, 0.282229965156794, 0.259604625139873, 0.05, 
0.0481163744871317, 0.21606648199446, 0.043731778425656, 0.198433420365535, 
0.212543554006969, 0.21606648199446, 0.196195449459157, 0.062111801242236, 
0.0982578397212544, 0.196195449459157, 0.0132404181184669, 0.0982578397212544, 
0.212543554006969, 0.196195449459157, 0.196195449459157, 0.0354345393509884, 
0.259604625139873)), .Names = c("id", "cars", "numb", "mysize"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -500L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

and this is the resulting plot with ggplot

```
ggplot(mydata,aes(x=numb, y=cars))+geom_point(aes(size=mysize))+geom_line(aes(group=id, color="blue"),  show.legend = FALSE)+theme_bw()
```

[image]

and the plot with Lattice

```
xyplot(cars~numb , type="b", col="black", col.line="blue",  data=mydata, pch=16, cex= mydata$mysize*3,  lwd=1 , groups= mydata$id)
```

[image]

As you can see the circles aren't equivalent.
I don't know which one is wrong.

PD2:
I've summarized the data keeping only unique pairs.

`poi <- unique(mydata, by=c("cars","numb"))`

```
structure(list(id = c(3059L, 1161L, 1511L, 294L, 596L, 2440L, 
446L, 2635L, 744L, 3495L, 6447L, 1040L, 1031L, 690L, 352L, 6311L, 
3758L, 6348L, 214L, 8192L, 615L, 6426L, 1686L, 2677L, 630L, 820L, 
1806L, 201L, 662L, 4420L, 2704L, 1111L, 734L, 3136L, 335L, 1967L, 
866L, 2844L, 685L, 221L, 1542L, 6707L, 4467L, 630L, 1691L, 201L, 
1259L, 5918L, 3545L, 3029L, 1939L, 1461L, 8150L, 866L, 4804L, 
4581L, 630L, 6378L, 6438L, 675L, 6205L, 4683L, 1699L, 8304L, 
1381L, 6348L, 8197L, 2386L, 1053L, 8197L, 4104L, 5202L), cars = structure(c(11L, 
12L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 
8L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 
10L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 8L, 13L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 
4L, 11L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 8L), .Label = c("FORD", 
"VW", "PEUGEOT", "RENAULT", "TOYOTA", "BMW", "NISSAN", "MB", 
"AUDI", "HONDA", "FIAT", "LR", "SKODA", "MAZDA", "MINI", "KIA", 
"VOLVO", "SEAT", "SUZUKI", "MITSU", "JAGUAR", "ROVER", "SAAB", 
"LEXUS", "CHEVRO", "MG", "PORSCHE"), class = "factor"), numb = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 7L, 16L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L), mysize = c(0.196195449459157, 
0.259604625139873, 0.0982578397212544, 0.0761772853185596, 0.00627177700348432, 
0.0759581881533101, 0.0655052264808362, 0.198433420365535, 0.167701863354037, 
0.212543554006969, 0.120477433793361, 0.0664819944598338, 0.061917195076464, 
0.183673469387755, 0.307479224376731, 0.0512465373961219, 0.0484893696381947, 
0.142857142857143, 0.0115628496829541, 0.34402332361516, 0.375, 
0.0481163744871317, 0.0522648083623693, 0.282229965156794, 0.5, 
0.1, 0.0662020905923345, 0.0625, 0.0699708454810496, 0.00857888847444983, 
0.0682926829268293, 0.444444444444444, 0.0875, 0.0496894409937888, 
0.054016620498615, 0.0229965156794425, 0.4, 0.21606648199446, 
0.5, 0.0728862973760933, 0.322981366459627, 0.0354345393509884, 
0.0775623268698061, 0.1, 0.0125, 0.032069970845481, 0.0229965156794425, 
0.0204081632653061, 0.0683229813664596, 0.0375, 0.0138504155124654, 
0.0152354570637119, 0.0193905817174515, 0.2, 0.0318559556786704, 
0.0291545189504373, 0.5, 0.0132404181184669, 0.00484893696381947, 
0.00484893696381947, 0.0132404181184669, 0.031055900621118, 0.0248447204968944, 
0.0787172011661808, 0.0222222222222222, 1, 0.0124223602484472, 
0.0595567867036011, 0.05, 0.05, 0.043731778425656, 0.062111801242236
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), .Names = c("id", "cars", "numb", "mysize"))
```

Lattice doesn't produce the same result with this uniquefied dataset but at least is near what we want.

```
p1 <- xyplot(cars~numb , type="p", col="black",  data=poi, pch=16, cex= poi$mysize*3)
p2 <- xyplot(cars ~ numb , type = "l",  col.line = "blue",  data = mydata,   lwd = 1 , groups = mydata$id)
p1+as.layer(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: I see the differrence. I will run the code and have a look.

Comment: I noticed that 1 dot in the plot covers more than one "row of data".  For instance if you type the following: `library(dplyr) ; nrow(mydata %>% filter(cars=="LR" & numb<2) %>% droplevels())` , you will get 61 rows. I wonder whether this is playing here.

Comment: Another related question... How can use a different alpha for the points (alpha=1) and for the lines (alpha=0.3)?

Comment: The number of identical rows does play a role for the `lattice` plot but not for `ggplot`. I will update my answer with code and figures. You should think about whether this is what you want: overplotting a dot several times (different per dot) and not seeing it (ggplot) or see an increase in the size of the dot (lattice). Maybe you need a different way of visualizing.

Comment: I've updated the post with a dataset with unique pairs.  ggplot still produces the same result.  lattice now seems to be doing it well for the points but not for the lines. SKODA 13 should be connected to LR 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cex` parameter to set the size of the points in `lattice`.

The code may look like this, with some **invented** data:

```
library(lattice)

## some data invented on the spot
mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                     y = 6:10,
                     mysize =  1:5,
                     id = c(1,1,1,2,2))

xyplot(y ~ x , type = c("b"), col = c("black"), col.line = c("blue"), 
       data = mydata, pch = 21, cex = mydata$mysize,  lwd = 1 )
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

if you also want to use the grouping (as in your ggplot example), add a `groups` parameter:

```
xyplot(y~x , type=c("b"), col=c("black"), col.line=c("blue"), 
       data=mydata, pch=21, cex= mydata$mysize,  lwd=1 , groups= mydata$id)
```

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

### UPDATE

We can see that one dot is the result of overplotting of several data points: e.g. the car "LR" with numb "1" occurs 61 times.

```
library(dplyr) ; nrow(mydata %>% filter(cars=="LR" & numb<2))
# 61
```

Let us remove these LR--1 combinations (after saving on for later) and make sure there is just one of them present. Store in `mydata2`

```
OneRow <- head(mydata %>% filter(cars=="LR" & numb<2), 1)
mydata2 <- mydata %>% filter( !(cars=="LR" & numb<2))
mydata2 <- rbind(mydata2, OneRow)
```

Now plot with  `ggplot`

```
ggplot(mydata2, aes(x = numb, y = cars)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = mysize)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=id, color="blue"),  show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

and with `lattice` `xyplot()`

```
xyplot(cars ~ numb , type = "b", col = "black", col.line = "blue",  
       data = mydata2, pch = 16, 
       cex = mydata$mysize*3,  lwd = 1 , groups = mydata$id)
```

[image]

Comparing the two lattice plots makes it clear that, the multiplicity of the LR--1 combination plays a role in the size of the dot. If we want to - **and we need to know whether we want this ** - get the same result as with `ggplot` we need to have unique rows.

Comment: I'm having problems when applying this method to my dataset.
What's the best way to share it here?
It's too big to be pasted but small enough to be included as a csv file.

Comment: Couldn't you share part of your data. Big enough to make the "proof of concept" but not too big to share here? You should use `dput`. Look **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176460/how-to-paste-data-from-r-to-stackoverflow)** for a guide.

Comment: OK, I've just updated my post with a sample of the data and a visual example of what I've attained.

Comment: I will add the code to get the `ggplot`-like figure with the `lattice xyplot` under **UPDATE 2**.

Comment: If it's not too much time consuming for you it would be nice. Thanks.
This data is in "long format". I want to plot the time evolution...  But I could also transform it to a format with columns "from" and "to" and the "numb"  position of the first. Maybe that way would be easier to plot it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am blocked. You need the "id" field. If I try to find unique rows of "id", "numb", "cars", and "mysize" then it is just the old same dataset. The problem remains, repeated values of 1 dot location (numb) increases point size, regardless of the point size set with `cex`, by setting `cex` equal to a **vector** (`mysize`). If you set `cex` to a **constant**, `cex=2`, then the size remains unchanged by number of observations. I am sorry, but I can't seem to get any further. Maybe you can phrase a new question with what you have learned here. I will surely upvote your question!

Comment: Don't worry, don'y spend more time, thanks.
I think the complication is that we want to keep unique point but also unique jumps (lines).

Comment: I think we could try to create the graphic in a two-step aproach, first the unique points and then adding a new layer with the lines from the wole dataset.

Comment: Good Luck, I will help if I think I can.